# Is it right to use % symbol in a formula?

Tags: article-writing, percentages

I was told when calculating an error term I shouldn't use:
$$
    Error = 2\% \ast 100kg
$$

But that, formally, I should use:
$$
     Error = \frac{2 \ast 100kg}{100}
$$

Which one is right? Or are them both right?

Comment: The sign $\%$ is equivalent to $1/100$, so both formulas are identical.

Comment: I would say "2 percent of 100kg" rather than "2 percent times 100kg", so I would argue that they are *not* equivalent. (That is, 2% is not a number but rather corresponds to the number 0.02).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2$% represents the relative error on the weight, whatever it could be (in other words, it represents more or less the accuracy of the instrument).

Multiplying this $2$% by a given weight gives you the absolute error on the weight. So, if the weight is $100$ kg, the error (or the uncertainty) is $0.02   \times 100 = 2$ kg.

Comment: I understand the meaning, my question is about if I it is wrong to write 2% instead of 2/100. I'm not sure if you answered that. If you did I'm not understanding your answer..

Comment: In my opinion, it is wrong (but I can be wrong). Just phrase it like : for $100$ kg, I have an error of $2$% which means $2$kg for $100$ kg, then $0.02$kg per kg. Then, for $x$ kg, the error is $0.02 x$ kg. Is this clearer ?

Comment: Yes, thank you Claude!

Comment: @MiguelSorrohcotom. You are very welcome !

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the second one is correct. Basically 2%=2/100 but you cant write 2%*100, you'd better write (2/100)*100kg or 0,02*100kg

Comment: Why can't I write 2% * 100? Is it just a convention or does it have another reason?

Comment: I think it's just a convention